# Print only name of a class in Python

Tags: python

I’m learning Python 3.

My code

```
numbers = [1, 2]
print( type( numbers[0] ))
```

outputs

```
<class ‘int’>
```

How do I print only

```
‘int’
```

or

```
int
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__) attribute from the type.

```
>>> type(5).__name__
'int'
```

Or without using the [type built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```
>>> (5).__class__.__name__
'int'
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me who’s new (day 3) to Python.

Comment: You're welcome.